# How can I limit the space assigned to Déjà Dup backups?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I'd like to use Déjà Dup to backup my system on a remote file server. The backup itself is working fine. However, I haven't seen a way to limit the size of the backup and the configuration says the backups will be kept for at least x months or until the free space runs low. So I don't want my backup to eat up all the available disk space.

Is there a way to limit the backup size in Déjà Dup itself, or do I have to create a share on the server with limited space (some kind of shared mounted image with X GB of space)?

Answer (score 4):

Assign a disk quota on your backup account on the server, and deja-dup will take care of it.